# Drawing flipped Normal distribution in R without using coord_flip()

Tags: r, ggplot2, flip

Good day

Without using  coord_flip(), Is there a way to draw normal distribution flipped by exchanging position x and y in aes()?
I' ve tried as below.

```
df3 <- data.frame(x=seq(-6,6,b=0.1),y=sapply(seq(-6,6,b=0.1),function(x) dnorm(x))) 
ggplot(df3,aes(y,x))+ geom_line()  # x,y position exchanged
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'flipped'? If the same thing as `coord_flip()` then why not use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with `coord_flip`, but you can avoid it with `geom_path`. `geom_path` connects the points in the order they appear in the data, rather than in order of the magnitude of the x-value. So you just need to make sure the data are ordered by y-axis value (which they already are here).

```
ggplot(df3, aes(y,x)) + 
  geom_path() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: You mean you can't see the image in my answer when you try to view this web page in Chrome or IE on your computer?

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the geom_path()