# Several distributions in the same plot -- using geom_density function from ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I think I'm very close to getting this code done, but I'm missing something here.
I want to "combine" two plots into just one like this:

[image: Normal distributions]
The first plot has this code:

```
  ggplot(test, aes(y=key,x=value)) + 
  geom_path()+
  coord_flip()
```

And the second one has this one below:

```
  ggplot(test, aes(x=value, fill=key)) +
  geom_density() +
  coord_flip()
```

This kind of multiple distributions plot are often seen in stats book when we read about normal distributions. The most useful link I've got so far was this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621474/drawing-flipped-normal-distribution-in-r-without-using-coord-flip).

Please use this code to reproduce my question:

```
library(tidyverse)
test <- data.frame(key = c("communication","gross_motor","fine_motor"),
                   value = rnorm(n=30,mean=0, sd=1))
ggplot(test, aes(x=value, fill=key)) +
  geom_density() +
  coord_flip()

ggplot(test, aes(y=key,x=value)) + 
  geom_path(size=2)+
  coord_flip()
```

Thanks much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be interested in ridgeline plots from the [ggridges](https://github.com/clauswilke/ggridges) package.

> Ridgeline plots are partially overlapping line plots that create the impression of a mountain range. They can be quite useful for visualizing changes in distributions over time or space.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

set.seed(123)
test <- data.frame(
  key = c("communication", "gross_motor", "fine_motor"),
  value = rnorm(n = 30, mean = 0, sd = 1)
)

ggplot(test, aes(x = value, y = key)) + 
  geom_density_ridges(scale = 0.9) + 
  theme_ridges() +
  NULL
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.525
```

[image]

Add median line:

```r
ggplot(test, aes(x = value, y = key)) +
  stat_density_ridges(quantile_lines = TRUE, quantiles = 2, scale = 0.9) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_ridges() +
  NULL
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.525
```

[image]

Simulate a rug:

```r
ggplot(test, aes(x = value, y = key)) + 
  geom_density_ridges(
    jittered_points = TRUE,
    position = position_points_jitter(width = 0.05, height = 0),
    point_shape = '|', point_size = 3, point_alpha = 1, alpha = 0.7,
  ) +
  theme_ridges() +
  NULL
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.525
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: This answer is amazing! Thanks (I always right now looking at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291576/visualizing-multiple-size-distributions-in-one-plot, where I've found the old version of this package -- ggjoy). My hat's off to you

Comment: My pleasure to help!

Comment: @Luis: check these out too https://peerj.com/articles/4308.pdf & http://derekogle.com/fishR/2017-07-28-JoyPlot

Comment: awesome. I've got this "The
ggjoy package version 0.3.0 was used to compute and draw a kernel density estimate
(https://github.com/clauswilke/ggjoy). " to cite in my next papers. Thanks much again!

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do this is with `facet_wrap()`. If you don't like the default appearance of the facets you can tweak them with `theme()`, e.g.:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=value, fill=key)) +
    geom_density() +
    facet_wrap(~ key) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "mm"))
```

Result:

[image: density plots]

Comment: Thanks, but for a reason I don't know, when I have more than three labels (key), it splits my plot and use multiple lines. Is there any way to fix it and plot all results in the same row?

Comment: Try `facet_wrap(~ key, nrow = 1)` to force a single row layout.

Comment: Worked! Thanks, much!!